# Accessing prometheus web UI via Nginx ingress

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am trying to access prometheus with nginx ingress from http(80) port but I could not. I deployed Prometheus like following:

1. prometheus-deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: prometheus-deployment
  namespace: nginx-ingress
  labels:
    app: prometheus-server
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: prometheus-server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: prometheus-server
    spec:
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
            - matchExpressions:
              - key: monitoring
                operator: In
                values:
                - worker
      nodeSelector:
        monitoring: worker
      containers:
        - name: prometheus
          image: prom/prometheus
          args:
            - "--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml"
            - "--storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus/"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9090
          volumeMounts:
            - name: prometheus-config-volume
              mountPath: /etc/prometheus/
            - name: prometheus-storage-volume
              mountPath: /prometheus/
      volumes:
        - name: prometheus-config-volume
          configMap:
            defaultMode: 420
            name: prometheus-server-conf

        - name: prometheus-storage-volume
          emptyDir: {
```

2. prometheus-service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: prometheus-service
  namespace: nginx-ingress
  annotations:
      prometheus.io/scrape: 'true'
      prometheus.io/port:   '9090'

spec:
  selector:
    app: prometheus-server
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 9090
```

3. config-map.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: prometheus-server-conf
  labels:
    name: prometheus-server-conf
  namespace: nginx-ingress
data:
  prometheus.rules: |-
    groups:
    - name: devopscube demo alert
      rules:
      - alert: High Pod Memory
        expr: sum(container_memory_usage_bytes) > 1
        for: 1m
        labels:
          severity: slack
        annotations:
          summary: High Memory Usage
  prometheus.yml: |-
    global:
      scrape_interval: 5s
      evaluation_interval: 5s
    rule_files:
      - /etc/prometheus/prometheus.rules
    alerting:
      alertmanagers:
      - scheme: http
        static_configs:
        - targets:
          - "alertmanager.monitoring.svc:9093"

    scrape_configs:
      - job_name: 'node-exporter'
        kubernetes_sd_configs:
          - role: endpoints
        relabel_configs:
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_endpoints_name]
          regex: 'node-exporter'
          action: keep

      - job_name: 'kubernetes-apiservers'

        kubernetes_sd_configs:
        - role: endpoints
        scheme: https

        tls_config:
          ca_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
        bearer_token_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token

        relabel_configs:
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace, __meta_kubernetes_service_name, __meta_kubernetes_endpoint_port_name]
          action: keep
          regex: default;kubernetes;https

      - job_name: 'kubernetes-nodes'

        scheme: https

        tls_config:
          ca_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
        bearer_token_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token

        kubernetes_sd_configs:
        - role: node

        relabel_configs:
        - action: labelmap
          regex: __meta_kubernetes_node_label_(.+)
        - target_label: __address__
          replacement: kubernetes.default.svc:443
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_node_name]
          regex: (.+)
          target_label: __metrics_path__
          replacement: /api/v1/nodes/${1}/proxy/metrics

      - job_name: 'kubernetes-pods'

        kubernetes_sd_configs:
        - role: pod

        relabel_configs:
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape]
          action: keep
          regex: true
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_path]
          action: replace
          target_label: __metrics_path__
          regex: (.+)
        - source_labels: [__address__, __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_port]
          action: replace
          regex: ([^:]+)(?::\d+)?;(\d+)
          replacement: $1:$2
          target_label: __address__
        - action: labelmap
          regex: __meta_kubernetes_pod_label_(.+)
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
          action: replace
          target_label: kubernetes_namespace
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_name]
          action: replace
          target_label: kubernetes_pod_name

      - job_name: 'kube-state-metrics'
        static_configs:
          - targets: ['kube-state-metrics.kube-system.svc.cluster.local:8080']

      - job_name: 'kubernetes-cadvisor'

        scheme: https

        tls_config:
          ca_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
        bearer_token_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token

        kubernetes_sd_configs:
        - role: node

        relabel_configs:
        - action: labelmap
          regex: __meta_kubernetes_node_label_(.+)
        - target_label: __address__
          replacement: kubernetes.default.svc:443
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_node_name]
          regex: (.+)
          target_label: __metrics_path__
          replacement: /api/v1/nodes/${1}/proxy/metrics/cadvisor

      - job_name: 'kubernetes-service-endpoints'

        kubernetes_sd_configs:
        - role: endpoints

        relabel_configs:
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape]
          action: keep
          regex: true
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_scheme]
          action: replace
          target_label: __scheme__
          regex: (https?)
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_path]
          action: replace
          target_label: __metrics_path__
          regex: (.+)
        - source_labels: [__address__, __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_port]
          action: replace
          target_label: __address__
          regex: ([^:]+)(?::\d+)?;(\d+)
          replacement: $1:$2
        - action: labelmap
          regex: __meta_kubernetes_service_label_(.+)
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
          action: replace
          target_label: kubernetes_namespace
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_name]
          action: replace
          target_label: kubernetes_name
```

And I deployed nginx-ingress daemonset like follow:

1. nginx-ingress-daemonset.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
  namespace: nginx-ingress
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx-ingress
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx-ingress
      annotations:
        prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
        prometheus.io/port: "9090"
        prometheus.io/scheme: http
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: nginx-ingress
      containers:
      - image: nginx/nginx-ingress:2.0.3
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: nginx-ingress
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 80
          hostPort: 80
        - name: https
          containerPort: 443
          hostPort: 443
        - name: readiness-port
          containerPort: 8081
        - name: prometheus
          containerPort: 9090
        readinessProbe:
         httpGet:
           path: /nginx-ready
           port: readiness-port
         periodSeconds: 1
        securityContext:
          allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
          runAsUser: 101 #nginx
          capabilities:
            drop:
            - ALL
            add:
            - NET_BIND_SERVICE
        env:
        - name: POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        - name: POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        args:
          - -nginx-configmaps=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-config
          - -default-server-tls-secret=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/default-server-secret
         #- -v=3 # Enables extensive logging. Useful for troubleshooting.
         #- -report-ingress-status
         #- -external-service=nginx-ingress
          - -enable-prometheus-metrics
         #- -global-configuration=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-configuration
```

And my ingress resource like follow:

ingress-resource.yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: prometheus-ui
  namespace: nginx-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
  # Use the host you used in your kubernetes Ingress Configurations
  #- host: prometheus.example.com
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: prometheus-service
            port:
              number: 80
```

And this is my namespace output:

```
]# kubectl get all -n nginx-ingress -o wide
NAME                                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP             NODE    NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
pod/nginx-ingress-grhgj                      1/1     Running   0          24h   10.233.65.66   node2   <none>           <none>
pod/prometheus-deployment-7684888b99-whr4p   1/1     Running   0          26h   10.233.65.64   node2   <none>           <none>

NAME                         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE   SELECTOR
service/prometheus-service   ClusterIP   10.233.29.33   <none>        80/TCP    25h   app=prometheus-server

NAME                           DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR   AGE   CONTAINERS      IMAGES                      SELECTOR
daemonset.apps/nginx-ingress   1         1         1       1            1           <none>          25h   nginx-ingress   nginx/nginx-ingress:2.0.3   app=nginx-ingress

NAME                                    READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE   CONTAINERS   IMAGES            SELECTOR
deployment.apps/prometheus-deployment   1/1     1            1           26h   prometheus   prom/prometheus   app=prometheus-server

NAME                                               DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE   CONTAINERS   IMAGES            SELECTOR
replicaset.apps/prometheus-deployment-7684888b99   1         1         1       26h   prometheus   prom/prometheus   app=prometheus-server,pod-template-hash=7684888b99
```

And my ingress output:

```
# kubectl get ingress -n nginx-ingress
NAME            CLASS    HOSTS   ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
prometheus-ui   <none>   *                 80      10s
```

When I am trying to access prometheus via ingress in browser;
[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6bhz.png)

As you see, this is a default template of nginx. I cannot access to prometheus.
By the way, this VM's are in cloud. And I have not fqdn like xxx.com
I have public IP as you see picture and I am trying to access with this public IP.

I want to access via ingress with port 80. But I couldnt do that. What am i missing here?

Comment: your ingress supposed to get external ip.

```#kubectl get ingress -n nginx-ingress```
you have to have an ip external in your address